# How common is Stockholm-Syndrome and/or Codependency Issues in Battered-Wife(Person)-Syndrome and/or other abusive relationships?

Tags: emotional-abuse, physical-abuse, stockholm-syndrome

*This is an extremely sensitive topic so I apologize from the get-go if this is offensive in any way -- I am not meaning to. I am aware that there are a myriad of reasons as to why an individual that is being physically abused may continue a relationship or remain silent (fear/feels threatened for one's own life or family -- especially if children involved, financial/living expenses -- feel unable to survive logistically if they leave, the hope that the abuser will change and just needs love & support, low-self-esteem and feeling that they are not worthy of a better/healthier relationship, ignorance -- not even knowing what a healthy relationship looks like because they've grown up in an abusive household, societal norms/culture -- what will friends, family, neighbors, etc. think of me if they know what's really happening or it's a social taboo to flee, etc. etc. etc.). I am not a psychologist or a Social Service employees so I have no expertise in this area and don't claim to do so. I do not pass any judgement on anyone that stays in an abusive relationship as there are too many factors that I cannot even fathom.*

With that said, **I'm wondering how common is the is Stockholm-Syndrome and/or Codependency Issues in cases of Battered-Wife(Person)-Syndrome and/or other abusive relationships?** Is it common that traumatic-bonding occurs?